Reposting google map review
As a restaurant owner can I repost a google map review of my food on my social media accounts? Do I need to ask the owner of the review before I repost it?

You need permission of the copyright owner
For simplicity, we’ll assume that’s the owner of the account that posted the review.
They have given Google a licence for the content but they haven’t given that to anyone else. In addition, while Google can sub-licence for specific purposes, it’s limited to subcontractors of Google for the purposes of maintains the site.
